# Weird Bubbling Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, event-bubbling

I'm not sure why this is bubbling, but it is. Wondering if anyone has any ideas?

```
$('#file_upload').live('submit',function(event){
        $('#file_upload').attr('action','io.cfm?action=updateitemfile&item_id='+$('.agenda-modal').attr('data-defaultitemid'));
        $('iframe').load(function(){
            $('.upload_output').empty();
            $livepreview.agenda({
                action:'get',
                id:$('.agenda-modal').attr('data-defaultitemid'),
                type:'item',
                callback:function(json){
                    for(x in json[0].files){
                        $('.upload_output').append('<li class="file-upload"><a target="blank" href="io.cfm?action=getitemfile&item_file_id='+json[0].files[x].item_file_id+'">'+json[0].files[x].file_name+'</a> <a style="color:red" href="#deletefile-'+json[0].files[x].item_file_id+'">[X]</a></li>');
                    }
                    console.log('callback');
                }
            });
            console.log('iframed');
        });
        console.log('go');
    });
```

So, if I upload a files i get the following in my console:

```
go
iframe
callback
```

If i do it a 2nd time in a row:

```
go
iframed
iframed
callback
callback
```

and three times:

```
go
iframed
iframed
iframed
callback
callback
callback
```

etc.

I assumed if the `live()` event was bubbling "`go`" would bubble also, but it isn't. I tried `event.stropPropagation` just about everywhere inside of the submit, and `.die()` connected to the `$('#file_upload').die().live(...` like so.

Any ideas?

P.S. This `live()` call is just inside a jQuery doc load (`$(function(){...});`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `one` your issue should be resolved.

```
$('iframe').one("load", function() {
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Question though, will this still check if the iframe is loaded each time the form is submitted?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're attaching a *new/additional* [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) handler each time, this means the one your just added and all previous `load` event handlers are all running. If you want the handler to only run once, use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), instead of this:

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
```

use this:

```
$('iframe').one('load', function(){
```

or, a bit more wasteful but you could [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) each time:

```
$('iframe').unbind('load').load(function(){
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Question though, will this still check if the iframe is loaded each time the form is submitted?

Comment: @Oscar - Yup, it just won't run *every* `load` handler you attach, we're cleaning up the previous handlers from previous submits in each of the above solutions...it'll work like you want, give it a go :)